# User is Null in controller but in View has Value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, identity

I use `ASP.NET MVC 5` and `Identity` for `Authentication` , My problem is with belowe code :

```
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

`User` is Null , but I used Above code in View Like belowe and its work fine and user has Value .

```
  @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {...}
```

**what is matter ?**

to do this I search on google and find a way with

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
    }
```

Comment: Where do you use this code? If you are trying to do it in the constructor of your controller, then it will be null because that's too early.

Comment: I used `Initialize` in BaseController and other controllers inheritance that

Comment: Inside the `Initialize` method you should be able to access the HttpContext.

Comment: Could you tell us what you are trying to achieve? Perhaps we could suggest a different way of doing what you are trying to do.

Comment: I try with `HttpContext` and its null too

Comment: Try **after** calling the `base.Initialize(requestContext)`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov your right , I called method in constructor , I removed in constructor and solve it , thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suspect that you are trying to call this method inside the constructor of a controller. This constructor is called too early in the HTTP request execution pipeline and the HttpContext is not available there. You can access the HttpContext inside the Initialize method:

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
    base.Initialize(requestContext);

    // Now you can access the HttpContext and User
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```